# Dynamic AJAX URL javascript

Tags: jquery, ajax

if have an AJAX which works fine, like this one

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var myURL = "";
$(document).ready(function(){


$("#advancedUpload").uploadFile({
    url:myURL,
    allowedTypes:"csv",
    fileName:"myfile"
});


$(".cbs").on('change', function(){
        if($('.cbs:checked').length !== 0){
            myURL = "my.php?action=upload";
            $(".cbs:checked").each(function(){
                myURL += "&" + $(this).attr('name') + "=" + $(this).val() ;
            });
        }else{
        }
            );
    });
});
```

The problem is I want to change the `var req` everytime I check a checkbox, and it's also working, I can change the variable value. But my AJAX is still referring to the initial value of the variable. Anyone have an idea why is that?

Thanks.

Comment: Most programmers looking at your question will have a hunch on what this is about. It's probably scope related. But most programmers are also uncomfortable taking guessing and making assumptions. Would you be so kind to create a [mcve] of your problem? We're interested in how you defined your functions and how you are calling those functions.

Comment: I edited my post. Look, I set a variable myURL that should be a URL for the AJAX. Everytime I check a checkbox, that URL changes. It changes, it works. But the problem is, AJAX still get's the initial value which is (" ") blank when I call the function of AJAX. IDK why. @AndreiGheorghiu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using [`jQueryUploadFile`](http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php#doc) plugin, you should call its `update()` method to change the initial `url` option:

```js
$(document)
  .ready(function () {

    var Upload = $("#advancedUpload")
      .uploadFile({
        url: "",
        allowedTypes: "csv",
        fileName: "myfile"
      });

    $(".cbs")
      .on('change', function () {
        if ($('.cbs:checked').length !== 0) {
          var myURL = "my.php?action=upload";
          $(".cbs:checked").each(function () {
            myURL += "&" + $(this).attr('name') + 
                     "=" + $(this).val();
          });
          Upload.update({
            url: myURL
          })
        } else {
          Upload.update({
            url: ""
          })
        }
      });
  });
```

Please note I haven't tested it but, from what I read in their docs, it should work.

Comment: This is just what I need, minimum lines of code. It worked man! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to reinit jQuery upload file to change target upload url. It was setup once on init $("#advancedUpload").uploadFile({...config...}) and doesn't have link with it variable.

Or there is better variant:

---

`$("#advancedUpload").uploadFile({
    url: "my.php?action=upload",
    allowedTypes:"csv",
    fileName:"myfile",
    dynamicFormData: function(){
        var data = {}; 
        if($('.cbs:checked').length !== 0){
            $(".cbs:checked").each(function(){
                data[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
            });
        }
       return data;
   }
});`

Is this what you want?

---

Or to real update url use API method `uploadObj.update({url: updatedUrl});`
where uploadObj must be your `$("#advancedUpload").uploadFile({..});`

Comment: Can you expand your solution please?

Comment: I see you don't need to change url in your ajax request. You can use dynamicFormData [doc](http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php#doc) param to send it. See **6)**. Put your change callback here and enjoy.
`var data = {};
data[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
return data;`

Add need condition for you, when you need to send it or not.